# How to add Samarium atom type in Autodock Vina?

Tags: docking, autodock

While trying to perform docking of a protein containing Samarium atom using Autodock-vina in Ubuntu, the following error arises. "**ATOM syntax incorrect: "Sm" is not a valid AutoDock type. Note that AutoDock atom types are case-sensitive.**" Following similar queries, I tried adding the parameters of the atom to the AD4_parameters.dat and AD4.1_bound.dat files yet couldn't resolve the problem. Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question?